# Change phone number

Tags: html

I'm trying to understand how to access the phone number here:

```
<div class="address__location">
  <p>
    Siddals Road
    <br> Derby DE1 2QD
  </p>
  <p>Main Phone:
    <a href="tel:0800123123&#10;         ">0800123123</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I need to find the html element of the phone number so I can replace it with another number.

So if I were to use getElementbyID"xxx" it would return the phone number.

Comment: You can't use getElementById, since you don't have id attribute inside this link. Is your .address_location only div with that class in your html?

Comment: You add the `id` attribute to the `a`. Otherwise there's no `id` to look for.

Comment: Thanks, what about document.querySelector, could I use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `id` attribute set on that element.

You could use another selector, though, by using `document.querySelector` and passing `a[href^="tel:"]`. This will search for `a` elements that have an `href` attribute that starts-with (*that is what `^=` means*) the text `tel:`.

so

```
var telephoneNode = document.querySelector('a[href^="tel:"]');

telephoneNode.textContent = 'some other phone'; // change the displayed text
telephoneNode.href = 'some other url'; // change the href and in effect where the link points to
```

Comment: Oh cool! thanks a lot this really helps, very interesting.  cheers